# Next.js: How to disable telemetry permanently in all environments?

Tags: next.js

I want to disable Next.js telemetry in all environments, forever (Just because, Ok?  Let's not sidetrack the question with irrelevant debate).

I don't want the telemetry to run on developer environments, test builds, CI builds or anywhere else.
I'm trying to find a "code" solution - I don't want to have to do anything manually in an environment in order to switch off telemetry.

Next.js makes it difficult to figure out if telemetry is enabled because it only prints the telemetry warning once on a given machine.

My diagnostic for knowing if telemetry is running is to add the `next telemetry status` command to my `build` script in `package.json`:

```json
"build": "next telemetry status && next build",
```

I've tried adding the following to `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED: '1',
  },
}
```

And I've tried adding this to `.env`:

```
NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1
```

But the telemetry command still reports `Status: Enabled`

In fact, the `NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED` env variable doesn't seem to work at all, I tried manually disabling telemetry in my IDE by setting the env variable, but it still reports telemetry is enabled:

[image]

- Next.js version: 9.5.2
- Doco: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
- Github issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8851

Comment: Vercel doesn't want you to disable analytics, so they've gone out of their way to make it difficult. When you run `next telemetry status`, it probably doesn't account for your repo's `.env` file. There's deliberately no easy way to check whether a code-level setting has disabled telemetry. Even if you try to check by running your next app, you won't know whether it worked because next only reports whether it's sending telemetry the first time. You can't event experiment with this in a fresh Docker container, because it detects Docker and behaves differently.

Comment: @Steve That's definitely the impression that I got.  The doco (at the time, at least) implied that telemetry could be disabled but they seem to have gone out of their way to make that not practical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding `next telemetry disable` command as my `prebuild` script seems to have done the trick.

```json
"prebuild": "next telemetry disable",
"build": "next build",
```

Comment: Does this work across all environments? Like on a local dev server, and production?

Comment: @dokgu you might consider adding other "pre"-scripts like "predev" 
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts